# Rails form_for form sending nil without letting displaying the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms

EDIT: I managed to fix the problem. The Ship controller was in the Ship method.  If I'm understanding the problem, my routes were calling "get products/ship" which was calling the method without showing the view.  After rearranging things, everything works fine.

This must be a beginner thing that I am overlooking, but I have a form in a rails 4.2.1 app made with form_for.

My problem is that I am not able to actually SEE the form, it won't display whatsoever.  Worse yet, rather than seeing the page view, it simply passes nil through to the method and gives me errors because my methods obviously don't work for nil.

I have tried playing around with the routes file to no avail, is there something simple that I'm missing that would just cause a form to behave in this way?  I've consulted the official guides and the hartl tutorial, but I've got nothing.

EDIT: My controller for product is below:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController



def new
        @product = Product.new
  end

def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
end

def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:code])
end


def ship
    @product = Product.find_by(code: params[:code])
    @product.quantity -= 1
    if @product.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {}
            format.json{}
        end
    end
end

private
      def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:code, :product, :quantity)
    end

end
```

and my view for the ship method is below:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :code %>
        <%= f.text_field :code %>

        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I would be so grateful for any help.  I've been staring at this for so long and there has to be something I'm missing.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got `<%= form_for...` or `<% form_for...` ?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: I've got it with the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

for html.erb, to inject the ruby into the html you need the equal sign, like so

<%= for_for

for haml its just an = sign

= form_for

Comment: No, I have the equal sign there.